# Approximation of a standard normal random variable in probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $Z$ be standard normal random variable and $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a real sequence with $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$. Can we obtain something like 
$$P(Z>a_n)\leq \exp(- c_n)$$ where $c_n$ is another real sequence with $c_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$. And if there is a result like this how does $c_n$ look like?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $z\gt0$,
$P[Z\gt z]\leqslant C(z)$, where
$$
C(z)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac1z\mathrm e^{-z^2/2}.
$$
This is asymptotically optimal since
$$
P[Z\gt z]\geqslant\frac{z^2}{z^2+1}\,C(z).
$$
In your context, one can choose
$$
c_n=\tfrac12a_n^2+\log(a_n)+\tfrac12\log(2\pi).
$$
**Edit:** To show the first upper bound above note that, if $z\gt0$ then $t/z\gt1$ for every $t$ in $(z,+\infty)$ hence, for every $z\gt0$,
$$
P[Z\gt z]\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_z^\infty\frac{t}z\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\mathrm dt=\frac{-1}{z\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\left.\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\right|_z^\infty=C(z).
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick answer! That's really helpful!

Comment: Do you know if this result has a name? Thanks!

Comment: I think it does not (have a name).

Comment: Could you give me a hint how to proof this result. Thanks:)

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $